# Python/Django : while trying to connect Django with database, get error - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0b1'

Tags: python, django

After updating oracle database information in settings.py file, i tried to run manage.py inspectdb command and i am getting error below. Any help in figuring out the issue is greatly appreciated.

After updating oracle database information in settings.py file, i tried to run manage.py inspectdb command and i am getting error below. Any help in figuring out the issue is greatly appreciated.

```
C:\Users\aupadhyay\Desktop\myproj>python manage.py inspectdb > klog_batch_dev1_user/models.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 367, in execute_f rom_command_line utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 341, in execute django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django__init__.py", line 27, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 199, in import_models self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "", line 986, in _gcd_import File "", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 665, in exec_module File "", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 119, in new new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 316, in add_to_class value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_cl ass self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\db__init__.py", line 33, in getattr return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\db\utils.py", line 211, in getitem backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\db\utils.py", line 115, in load_backend return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 63, in from .operations import DatabaseOperations # NOQA isort:skip
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\db\backends\oracle\operations.py", line 14, in from .utils import InsertIdVar, Oracle_datetime, convert_unicode
  File "C:\Users\aupadhyay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py3.5.egg\django\db\backends\oracle\utils.py", line 10, in (int(Database.version.split('.', 2)[1]) >= 1 or ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0b1'
```

Comment: `0b1`, is that supposed to be a binary representation?

Comment: Can you show the database settings code?

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'DUMMYDEV1',
        'USER': 'dummy_dev1_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'dummy_123',
    }
}

Comment: Check the codification of your database and the character that are you trying to store on it.

Answer (score 1):

You're apparently using a beta version of Oracle, which leads to a parsing error when it's trying to get Oracle's version. Either up/downgrade to a production version or [file a bugreport](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/internals/contributing/bugs-and-features/), so that it can handle version suffixes like "b1" for "beta 1".